# Using match() in excel vba shows me an error

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste data in an array which I saved from another workbook to a specific cell. The destination cell is chosen on 2 matches:

1. Row position is got from the code column
2. Column position is got from the day row

With this cell information, I want to paste data to that field. It is in a loop, because I have to enter 9 of those data to respective cell.

```
Sub copyData()

    Dim source As Workbook

    Dim Machine(1 To 9, 1 To 2)
    Dim r As Byte, c As Byte
    Dim day As Byte
    Dim rowCode As Long
    Dim colmnDay As Long

    Const StartRow As Long = 6
    Const StartColumn As Long = 1

    Set source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\MONTH_DATA.xlsx", True, True)

     day = source.Worksheets("day 1").Range("W20").Value

    For r = 1 To 9
        For c = 1 To 2
            Machine(r, c) = source.Worksheets("day 1").Cells(r + StartRow, c + StartColumn).Value
        Next c
    Next r

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    For r = 1 To 9
        For c = 1 To 2
            colmnDay = WorksheetFunction.Match(day, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F1:J5"), 0)
            rowCode = WorksheetFunction.Match(Machine(r, 1), Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E2:E9"), 0)

            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(rowCode, colmnDay).Value = Machine(r, 2)


            'Let row1 = "A" & r
            'Let row2 = "B" & r
            'Worksheets("sheet1").Range(row1).Value = Machine(r, 1)
            'Worksheets("sheet1").Range(row2).Value = Machine(r, 2)
        Next c
    Next r


    Workbooks("MONTH_DATA.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

It does: Store these variables "day, Machine(code, value)" successfully from the workbook MONTH_DATA by opening it. VBA is running from another workbook.

Expected result: match() needs to get me the row & column position of matched code & day. With that cell info I can paste the value into it.

I get an error

> "Unable to get Match property of WorksheetFunction class"

at line

```
rowCode = WorksheetFunction.Match(Machine(r, 1), Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E2:E9"), 0)
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56099254/4961700

Comment: Nope. the code has been changed and with a new error

Comment: So, what have you found out about the error? Or what have you found out about the function? Have you checked the data exists or is in range that the function calls?

Comment: In your workbook do you have a sheet called "sheet1" or "day 1" ?

Comment: data matching is one saved in an array with the columns (code), and other just a variable (day) in the row. I am not pretty sure how match() work in my case. But I made it as perfect I can after watching some examples

Comment: Why not try match() on some simple data on a worksheet so you know what to expect. Then you may be able to sort this....

Comment: sheet1 in the workbook am about to get the result and day 1 in the workbook i copied data's to variable

Comment: So, how are you changing focus between the workbooks - you seem to suggest you are working with two... You need to tell vba **exactly** which workbook it needs to look in for the variable or data you want.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MQyHQ4c.png in here, 1. is the workbook I copied data, 2. is the position am pasting

Comment: Data in the workbook "MONTH_DATA" sheet name "day 1" is copied to variables day, Machine(code, value). In the stored data matching "day, code" value to new workbook and pasting corresponding value there

Comment: What do you expect the output of the match() function to be? and how do you expect to use it?

Comment: I expect it to give me the row, column position where the value  has to be paste

Comment: the files i am using : https://gofile.io/?c=ZPoel1

Comment: Sorry, I don't open files ad lib... update your question as necessary.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Match(day, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F1:J5"), 0)`. Try creating the `Match` function first in the worksheet and you'll get an error. `F1:J5` is not a valid range.

Comment: O yeah, it was F1:J1..

Comment: but it now stops in next line, E2:E9 is valid there !

Comment: should this "rowCode = WorksheetFunction.Match(Machine(r, 1)" be "rowCode = WorksheetFunction.Match(Machine(r, c)" ? so it picks up 1 or 2 depending what c is set to?

Comment: Removed the for loop for c from there, column c1 have all codes, c2 have all values.

Comment: Error still there, Machine(r,1) gives the code in the corresponding row (-> 1 - 9) and Machine(r,2) is repective value of it

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wJhPF6r.png this is the locals window appears when I stop the process at End Sub

Comment: Issue was, It was first matching for code 100, which I didn't entered in new workbook. That solved issue